# How to stop auto commit in EJB-JPA tx

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, ejb

I have a stateless EBJ and I am using JPA to manage database interactions. Below is my scenario where I need your help.

1. EJB received the call to fetch data (getCustomer()).
2. GetCustomer is used to read Customer entity from database using JPA.
3. The customer entity is having a method to remove spaces from attributes.  which is annotated with @PostLoad. Basically this modifies the entity within persistence context.

Now when response is sent to client (after transaction completed ), its fires an update SQL to database to update the dataset (modified in step-3).

If you can see this operation, its a read-only in nature. But as my data is having lot many spaces, hence I have to trim it within entity object. But this approach is firing an update SQL which is not expected.

Could you please let me know the best approach to fix this issue or how to isolate and synchronize) EJB tx and JPA tx.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your getCustomer() to not support transactions:

```
@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
public Customer getCustomer()
```

Read more about transactions in the Java EE tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions003.htm

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for quick response-  getCustomer is a DAO method and this TransactionAttribute is a ejb annotation.  I can not use *ejb annotations in DAO layer. This annotation worked between client & business, but I need a similar solution between business & DAO (database).

Comment: Why don't you make your DAO an EJB?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to mess with transaction management to achieve your requirement.

Your code should invoke [javax.persistence.EntityManager.clear()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--) before returning from your DAO. This will detach your entity bean from the persistence context, which will no longer track it. From the java doc:

> Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted.